# C++ class design with polymorphism

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, c++14

I am doing some networking stuff, but the question is not related to networking. I have a generic network event handler, where I can register an network connection ("NwConnection" class) and idea is whenever a message arrives on the connection, it will call me back.

```
class NwEventManager {
public:

    using CallBack = std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<NwConnection>)>;

    registerCallback(
           std::shared_ptr<NwConnection> con,            
            CallBack rdCallback,
            CallBack errorCallBack);
};
```

So the application will create a NwConnection and register with Event Manager.
(NwConnection is an abstract class, which internally can be a TCP/Unix domain socket etc.)

Anyway, I need to keep some per-connection information, say some statisctics.

Currently what I am doing is:

```
class TcpNwConnection : public NwConnection {...}

class MyNwConnection : public TcpNwConnection {

   using NwConnection::NwConnection;

   ....
   MyStatistics& getStats ()
   {
       return myStats_;
   }

private:

   MyStatistics   myStats_;

};
```

And in the callback, which will call me back with the NwConnection Abstract class I static cast the pointer to my type and access the stats.

```
// read callback

[] (std::shared_ptr<NwConnection> con)
{
     auto myConn = static_cast<MyNwConnection *>(con.get());

     auto& stats = myConn->getStats();   
}
```

Is this a good approach?

Obviously the problem is, if my code has to be independant of the NwConnection type, say I want to deal with TcpConnection and UnixConnection, I cannot follow this approach (unless I do with templates).

One solution is to re-write things with connection type inside the NwConnection:

```
class TcpStream : public AbstractStream {}
class UnixStream : public AbstractStream {}

class NwConnection {

    Message read (...)
    {
        return stream->read(...);
    }

private:
    AbstractStream *stream;
};
```

Now I can do my static_cast and the type of connection doesnt matter.

But what is a better way to design this thing, while allowing applications to keep the per-connection data? (I am free to rewrite any part of the code.)

Comment: If your code works as expected, as you seem to indicate, and you are looking for ways of improving it, you should post it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Make sure to go through its [how to ask page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask there.

Comment: You'd typically use a dynamic cast when getting the concrete type and the check for null. However, I think you should design things such that casting to the concrete type is not required. Inherit from an interface the has GetStats as a pure virtual and implement it in your concrete class. Unless you have different statistic types for each concrete network class type too...

Comment: @ChristopherPisz, Statistics is just the requirement of one class. Since NwConnection is a generic class which different types of applications would want to use. Each concrete class would like to keep its own type of data in the connection.

Comment: @MGH in that case, I don't see an alternative to what you already have. That's how I'd do it too.

Comment: I'd use the second approach - making a separate class with stream interface to do stats, sort or wrapper. In this case, you decouple stats counting from an actual data transfer code. And you can keep it inside `NwEventManager` - take a generic interface as a parameter, wrap it with stats counting class and keep it. Since `NwEventManager` will create wrapper it can store it as a concrete type.

Comment: You could template up the registration so that the registered callback takes an explicit derived type, and must be registered with an object of that type. Internally, obviously, your dispatcher would need to store the pointer as base class, and the function as probably void* and cast back up before calling the callback, but that cast is safe, as the caller was forced to register using that type of object. Probably this casting is easiest done in a lambda helper function taking these 2 as arguments declared inside the template registration function. Sadly, we now register 3 things instead of 2.